# How do i implement ScrimInsetFrameLayout to my navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, material-design

Hi I'm trying to implement ScrimInsetFrameLayout so my navigation drawer will fill the status bar will be behind just like the Play Store app from Google I'm using the scriminsetframelayout, first I put this code in to my workspace in android studio https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.java then I modify this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.myapp.app.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="@dimen/navdrawer_width"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:id="@+id/navdrawer"
android:background="@color/navdrawer_background"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:insetForeground="#4000">


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Main layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_content_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Nav drawer -->
    <com.app.aacplayer.view.DrawerView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</com.myapp.app.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>
```

but is not working my app just crash and quit. I need some advises to achieve this please, thank you very much.

here's my current code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <com.app.aacplayer.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/navdrawer"
        android:background="@color/drawer_bg"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:insetForeground="#4000">

    <!-- Main layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_content_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </com.app.aacplayer.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>
    <!-- Nav drawer -->
    <com.app.aacplayer.view.DrawerView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: for starters you could put the `<?xml` declaration at the top of the file. once you do that, if it still crashes post logcat

Comment: im getting this: Error:(3) No resource identifier found for attribute 'insetForeground' in package 'com.app.app.dev'

Comment: you have to copy the attr definitions for `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout` from iosched's `res/values/attr.xml` file to your project

Comment: I stand corrected: `ScrimInsetsView` from [this file](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml)

Comment: yeah i just copied: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ScrimInsetsView">
        <attr name="insetForeground" format="reference|color" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>

Comment: should i remove my current linearlayout? because when i do it then my navigation drawer changes and looks strange all menu items disorganized

Comment: and when i dont remove linearlayout then navigation looks good but not behind the status bar like it should be

Comment: Move the `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout` around the `LinearLayout`. That way it won't affect the drawer. Don't forget to keep the namespace declarations on the top element (now `DrawerLayout`).

Comment: i just edit my code is the last one in the main thread now my activity dissapeared its strange i cant see anything just black

Comment: `</com.lamega983.aacplayer.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>` belongs right after `</LinearLayout>`

Comment: yeah i tried that too now when i open navigation drawer my main activity shows inside

Comment: The way you wrote it makes no sense. The `DrawerLayout` is supposed to have two children: first is the content view (in your case the linear layout wrapped in ScrimInsetsFrameLayout for proper statusbar coloring), second is the drawer.

Comment: i just fix what u said to put the scrim line after linearlayout but nothing all is blank :(

Comment: Review the code, there are some attributes on the scrim layout which should be on the drawer view (background, width). Also the main content (scrim layout) should have no gravity.